# How to replace an object containing react components with a single line of code?

Tags: reactjs, antd

In multiple components, I have an identical part of code. It provides 'ant-design' tables with properties necessary for filtering.

```js
getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({
      setSelectedKeys,
      selectedKeys,
      confirm,
      clearFilters
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={node => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e =>
            setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])
          }
          onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
        />
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
          icon="search"
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 90, marginRight: 8 }}
        >
          Search
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)}
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 90 }}
        >
          Reset
        </Button>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => (
      <Icon type="search" style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
      }
    },
    render: text => (
      <Highlighter
        highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ffc069", padding: 0 }}
        searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
        autoEscape
        textToHighlight={text && text.toString()}
      />
    )
  });
```

It's used in columns array like this:

```js
columns = [
  {
      title: "Client",
      dataIndex: "client",
      sorter: (a, b) => {
        if (a.client && b.client) {
          return a.client.localeCompare(b.client);
        } else {
          return a.client;
        }
      },
      sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
      ...this.getColumnSearchProps("client")
    }
]
```

I have a problem with figuring out the way to extract this code to a different file. It's a complex construction - an object with multiple properties and react components assigned to them. 
`filterDropdown` can be easily replaced by functional component but is it possible to replace the whole block with a single line?

I've tried to create a new js function `getColumnSearchProps` in a separate file. I replaced `ref={node => { this.searchInput = node; }}` with `const searchInput = React.createRef();` but that led to `searchInput.select is not a function` error.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the whole block of code to a different file, inside of a new function. 
All class properties (this) are passed as parameters. I'm sure it's not the most elegant way but it works.

The `searchInput.select is not a function` error was coused by incomplit path - `searchInput.select()` instead of `serachInput.current.select()`.

```js
const getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex, searchText) => {
  const searchInput = React.createRef();

  return {
    filterDropdown: ({
      setSelectedKeys,
      selectedKeys,
      confirm,
      clearFilters
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={searchInput}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e =>
            setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])
          }
          onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
        />
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
          icon="search"
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 90, marginRight: 8 }}
        >
          Search
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)}
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 90 }}
        >
          Reset
        </Button>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => (
      <Icon type="search" style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => searchInput.current.select());
      }
    },
    render: text => (
      <Highlighter
        highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ffc069", padding: 0 }}
        searchWords={[searchText]}
        autoEscape
        textToHighlight={text && text.toString()}
      />
    )
  };
};

export default getColumnSearchProps;
```

Answer (score 0):

i have updated the code, of search functionality in antd table component using hooks, if you stuck like me this code might help you, in latest coding with react hooks. it is working i will share the snippet too.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Table, Input, Button, Space } from "antd";
import Highlighter from "react-highlight-words";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Jim Red",
    age: 32,
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park"
  }
];

var searchInput = React.createRef();

const App = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [searchedColumn, setSearchedColumn] = useState("");

  const getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => {
    const customFilter = ({
      setSelectedKeys,
      selectedKeys,
      confirm,
      clearFilters
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={(node) => {
            searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])
          }
          onPressEnter={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => handleReset(clearFilters)}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="link"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => {
              confirm({ closeDropdown: false });
              setSearchText(selectedKeys[0]);
              setSearchedColumn(dataIndex);
            }}
          >
            Filter
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    );

    const customFilterIcon = (filtered) => (
      <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
    );

    const customOnFilter = (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        ? record[dataIndex]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase())
        : "";

    const customOnFilterDropdownVisibleChange = (visible) => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => searchInput.select(), 100);
      }
    };

    const customRender = (text) =>
      searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ffc069", padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ""}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      );

    return {
      filterDropdown: customFilter,
      filterIcon: customFilterIcon,
      onFilter: customOnFilter,
      onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: customOnFilterDropdownVisibleChange,
      render: customRender
    };
  };

  const handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    confirm();
    setSearchText(selectedKeys[0]);
    setSearchedColumn(dataIndex);
  };

  const handleReset = (clearFilters) => {
    clearFilters();
    setSearchText("");
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
      width: "30%",
      ...getColumnSearchProps("name")
    }
  ];

  return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
};

export default App;
```

[React snippet code](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-driscoll-9ue83?file=/src/App.js)